# How to combine data from several database tables into a single result table in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables in my Postgre SQL database:

- Table `Biodata`, `PRIMARY KEY (IdBiodata)`:

  ```
  IdBiodata     Nama           Alamat  
  -------------------------------------
  13            Singgih        Jakarta
  24            Arjuna         Surabaya
  ```
- Table `Telepon`, `FOREIGN KEY (IdBiodata)`:

  ```
  IdTelepon    IdBiodata   telepon   
  ------------------------------------
  1            13          08180898XXX
  2            13          08889153XXX
  3            24          08788823XXX
  ```

With the two tables, how to write a query in order to get the following results:

```
Nama      Alamat    Telepon  
---------------------------------
Singgih   Jakarta   08180898XXX
null      null      08889153XXX
Arjuna    Surabaya  08788823XXX
```

I've tried it, but did not find a solution, please help..

Comment: Surely you can dream up a meaningful title for this question. Also, it would be fantastic if you could clean up the formatting.

Comment: Are you sure there's no bigger font you could use?

Comment: my eyes paining while trying to read your ques

Comment: why would the second row be null if what i hear is that you want to select off of IdBiodata? I don't understand. Need more information.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct `idBiodata` in the second row of `Telepon`?

Comment: Hello there :D, i'am so sorry.. I was just learning to write, behold there was a typing error there, the last table is the result table. "2. Table Telepon FOREIGN KEY (IdBiodata)" unused;

Comment: Since `idBiodata` is a foreign key, joining it with `Biodata` can never be null. Foreign keys require that the row exist in the other table.

Comment: @Barmar, the first and the second table is my table in postgresql, and i want to display the exact same result as shown in the last table

Comment: I understand what they are, we don't understand how it should come up with that result. Why does the second telepon have a null name even though there is a matching row in the `Biodata` table.

Comment: @Killingsworth: the OP posted another question with more info, and has asked for your expertise once again (see comments on the answer below). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552440/error-i-report-in-java-web-application

Comment: @Barmar: the OP posted another question with more info, and has asked for your expertise once again (see comments on the answer below). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552440/error-i-report-in-java-web-application

Answer (score 1):

What you want is *probably* an `OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT Biodata.Nama, Biodata.Alamat, Telepon.telepon 
  FROM Biodata RIGHT OUTER JOIN Telepon ON Biodata.IdBiodata=Telepon.IdBiodata
```

Comment: I tried your code. Killingswort,  
Barmar and for the others who have responded to my question, here my problem is actually, please look at [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552440/error-i-report-in-java-web-application)

Comment: @Singgih: I'm not sure that the folks got notified (except for me, since you've commented on my answer). I've just posted a comment on this question with references to the people who have responded to your question, so that they are notified. See how it is done, for the next time :)

Comment: The new question is about the exact same query, and also about Java and I-Report, which I know nothing about. I'm not sure what I can add there.